# RAils Authlogic and Hobo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hobo

Is there anyone out there who has an idea of how to incorporate Hobo as an admin subsite on a existing rails app running on authlogic.

I've been following this [tutorial](http://cookbook.hobocentral.net/tutorials/subsite), but it not working.

Any help or Tutorial link please!

Some erorr code for anyone who fancies a crack:

```
~/dev/copy> ./script/server
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.4 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:426:in `load_missing_constant': Expected /Users/Mister/dev/copy/app/controllers/admin/admin_controller.rb to define Admin::AdminController (LoadError)
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:361:in `constantize'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:360:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:360:in `constantize'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:162:in `constantize'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hobo-1.0.0/lib/hobo/model_controller.rb:61:in `all_controllers'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hobo-1.0.0/lib/hobo/model_controller.rb:57:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hobo-1.0.0/lib/hobo/model_controller.rb:57:in `all_controllers'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hobo-1.0.0/lib/hobo/model_router.rb:97:in `add_routes_for'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hobo-1.0.0/lib/hobo/model_router.rb:83:in `add_routes'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hobo-1.0.0/lib/hobo/model_router.rb:83:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hobo-1.0.0/lib/hobo/model_router.rb:83:in `add_routes'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hobo-1.0.0/rails/../lib/hobo.rb:73:in `add_routes'
    from /Users/Mister/dev/copy/config/routes.rb:6
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:226:in `draw'
    from /Users/Mister/dev/copy/config/routes.rb:1
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:286:in `load_routes!'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:286:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:286:in `load_routes!'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:266:in `reload!'
    from /Users/Mister/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:537:in `initialize_routing'
    from /Users/Mister/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:188:in `process'
    from /Users/Mister/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /Users/Mister/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /Users/Mister/dev/copy/config/environment.rb:11
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Users/Mister/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from ./script/server:3
```

the environment and  gem in the app:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.4' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'
config.gem 'hobo'
config.gem "RedCloth", :version => ">= 4.2.2"
config.gem "authlogic"
  config.gem "cancan"
  config.gem "jrails"
  config.gem "peteonrails-vote_fu", :source => "http://gems.github.com", :lib => "vote_fu"
```

routes:

```
map.site_search  'search', :controller => 'admin/front', :action => 'search'
  map.admin '/admin', :controller => 'admin/front', :action => 'index'

  Hobo.add_routes(map)
```

Comment: Looks like you solved this? Could you answer yourself with the solution? Then mark this as closed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wild Guess...

In the `admin/admin_controller.rb` you have:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
   ...
end
```

and you need:

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

To cover the namespacing.

Comment: Already done the above Tony, it was will_paginate that was breaking the app, but cheers Dan